# How to add column inside postgres function without saving it to the db?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I have a postgres DB and I want to create a function that returns a copy of my table with a new column that has a value of 1 if its id is inside the array(idds[]) that the function gets as an input.
In the code below I've try to create a temporary table(chosen) that have id if it's in the idds array and to manually add the isChosen column that obviously doesn't work...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getTableFromArray(idds integer[])
    RETURNS table(
id INTEGER,
isChosen INTEGER
)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$


begin
with chosen AS(SELECT id,isChosen=1 FROM table1 WHERE ARRAY[table1.id] <@ idds)
return query
SELECT id FROM table1 LEFT JOIN chosen ON table1.id=chosen.id;

end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this query instead :

```
select * , case when ARRAY[table1.id] <@ idds then 1 else 0 end as choosen FROM table1;
```

so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getTableFromArray(idds integer[])
    RETURNS table(
id INTEGER,
isChosen INTEGER
)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'    
AS $BODY$
begin
return query
select id , case when ARRAY[table1.id] <@ idds then 1 else 0 end as isChosen FROM table1;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, with a lot less noise, a proper `boolean` output column, and without the unhelpful CaMeL case identifiers in a plain SQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_table_from_array(idds integer[])
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, is_chosen bool)
  LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT t.id, t.id = ANY(idds) FROM table1 t';
```

Might as well just run the SQL command directly, though:

```
SELECT id, id = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[]) AS is_chosen FROM table1;
```